# Creating a Github actions workflow deploy.yaml file and getting an error

Tags: github, yaml, workflow

I am trying to create my first Github actions workflow, and I am getting an error that online research is not helping me to solve.
This is quite a basic workflow right now for a WordPress site. It is failing at the "fetch-depth: 0" line. **If I remove the code below that line, the workflow runs fine.**
I have been checking indentation, and looking at online examples.

```
name: deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      # Pushing to the `master` branch
      # will trigger our workflow
      - master
    paths-ignore:
      # Ignore files and folders
        - 'bin/**'
        - 'readme.html'
concurrency:
  #maximum of one deployment in progress and one deployment pending at a time
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
permissions:
  actions: write
  contents: read
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        # Checkout our repository under `${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}`,
        # so our workflow can access it
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          # Fetch the entire Git history. 
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Deploy via SFTP
          #Deploy via FTP details
          uses: actions/checkout@v4
          with:
            host: ${{ secrets.MW_FTP_SERVER }}
            port: ${{ secrets.MW_FTP_PORT }}
            user: ${{ secrets.MW_FTP_USER }}
            pass: ${{ secrets.MW_FTP_PASS }}
            remoteDir: '/httpdocs'
            options: '--verbose'
```

Comment: So it seems you can run the workflow and find out the errors in the actions -> runs section on github!
In my case the error is: 

Unexpected input(s) 'host', 'port', 'user', 'pass', 'remoteDir', 'options', valid inputs are ['repository', 'ref', 'token', 'ssh-key', 'ssh-known-hosts', 'ssh-strict', 'persist-credentials', 'path', 'clean', 'filter', 'sparse-checkout', 'sparse-checkout-cone-mode', 'fetch-depth', 'fetch-tags', 'show-progress', 'lfs', 'submodules', 'set-safe-directory', '***-server-url']